# aws-iot device and jobs looses connections in the same process

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I have a connection to using the device sdk

```
const device = awsIot.device(config.DeviceOptions);
```

I want also to use the new jobs sdk

```
const jobs = awsIot.jobs(config.DeviceOptions);
```

then i get

> ```
> connect
> offline
> connection lost - will attempt reconnection in 1 seconds...
> close
> reconnect
> ```

how is it possible to use both in the same process without the connections problems?

i use it like below

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
var SystemInfo = require('./trace/systeminfo');
// var JobsModule = require('./jobs/jobs');

var config = require('./config');

const device = awsIot.device(config.DeviceOptions);
const jobs = awsIot.jobs(config.DeviceOptions);

var timeout;
var count = 0;
const minimumDelay = 250;


device.subscribe('topic_2');


device
    .on('connect', function () {
        console.log('connect');
    });
device
    .on('close', function () {
        console.log('close');
    });
device
    .on('reconnect', function () {
        console.log('reconnect');
    });
device
    .on('offline', function () {
        console.log('offline');
    });
device
    .on('error', function (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    });
device
    .on('message', function (topic, payload) {
        console.log('message', topic, payload.toString());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer each connection to the aws should have a unique clientId.

If you have shadow, device and job running than we created for connection its own unique clientId

```
var thingShadows = awsIot.thingShadow({
   keyPath: <YourPrivateKeyPath>,
  certPath: <YourCertificatePath>,
    caPath: <YourRootCACertificatePath>,
  clientId: <YourUniqueClientIdentifier>,
      host: <YourCustomEndpoint>
});
```

what we did is did

```
var device = awsIot.device({
   keyPath: <YourPrivateKeyPath>,
  certPath: <YourCertificatePath>,
    caPath: <YourRootCACertificatePath>,
  clientId: 'device -'+thingName,
      host: <YourCustomEndpoint>
});

var thingShadows = awsIot.thingShadow({
   keyPath: <YourPrivateKeyPath>,
  certPath: <YourCertificatePath>,
    caPath: <YourRootCACertificatePath>,
  clientId: 'thingShadows-'+thingName,
      host: <YourCustomEndpoint>
}); 

var jobs = awsIot.jobs({
   keyPath: <YourPrivateKeyPath>,
  certPath: <YourCertificatePath>,
    caPath: <YourRootCACertificatePath>,
  clientId: 'jobs-'+thingName,
      host: <YourCustomEndpoint>
});
```